# How to sort an array in descending alphabetical order in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt, ultraesb

I am new to Jolt.

Please how do I *sort* the following array in ***descending*** alphabetical order

**Input** :

```json
[
  {
    "status": [
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR",
      "REJECT",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want status REJECT to be the first object, so the output is:

```json
[
  {
    "status": [
      "REJECT",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR",
      "ERROR"
    ]
  }
]
```

I have seen the jolt **sort** operation:

```json
{
  "operation": "sort"
}
```

But, how to I point it at the status array and also specify I need a descending sort please?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `xslt`?

Comment: because of transferable skills

Comment: I have no clue what that means. Are you interested in XSLT answer? If not, please remove the tag. If yes, post your XSLT attempt.

Comment: You are right, it could be misleading. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XPath 3.1 can do [that](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xpath31fiddle/?xpath=%5B%20%0A%20map%20%7B%20%27lender-status%27%20%3A%20array%20%7B%20sort%28%3F1%3Fstatus%3F*%29%20%3D%3E%20reverse%28%29%20%7D%20%7D%0A%5D&input=%5B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22status%22%20%3A%20%5B%20%22ERROR%22%2C%20%22ERROR%22%2C%20%22REJECT%22%2C%20%22ERROR%22%2C%20%22ERROR%22%2C%20%22ERROR%22%2C%20%22ERROR%22%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%20%5D&input-type=JSON):

```
[ 
 map { 'lender-status' : array { sort(?1?status?*) => reverse() } }
]
```

Or with

```
[ 
 map { 'lender-status' : array:sort(?1?status) => array:reverse() }
]
```

Of course any XPath 3.1 solution can also be used in XSLT 3.0 or XQuery 3.1. I see you removed the xslt tag while I wrote the answer but I will post it as an alternative anyway.

Comment: I need a Jolt solution please! That might be useful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

If ***ascending order*** was the case, then you can easily match each components of the array with theirselves to make `"ERROR" : "ERROR"` and `"REJECT" : "REJECT"` pairs within a **shift** transformation, and apply **sort** transformation.

But, unfortunately there's no direct method to get the ***descending order*** whereas a workaround might be given through reversely indexing the components of the array such as

```json
[
  { // reform subarrays with repeating components and having keys identical to those repeated components
    // each subarray will be sorted in alphabetical order spontaneously 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "status": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&3.&[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert arrays to attributes by matching each common key with each component 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&1&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert whole content to a unique array back, named "status" 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // prepare "key" and "val" arrays to be used within the upcoming specs
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.key.&",
          "@": "&2.val"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "sz__": "=size(@(1,key))",
        "sz_": "=divide(@(1,sz__),-1)",
        "sz": "=toInteger(@(1,sz_))",
        "key": {
          "*": "=intSum(@(1,&),@(2,sz))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get "key" and "val" arrays
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": {
          "*": {
            "@": "&3.&2"
          }
        },
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // match each components of those arrays among them
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "key": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,val[&])": "&3.@(3,key[&])"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // sort by keys
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  { // convert attributes back to a unique array 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Barbaros. Thanks so much for this. Its appreciated. I will share some details soon.